# How do I pass props from top navigation to screen within a nested navigation in react navigation 5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have a case where I have a nested navigator setting.
The app.js holds the loggedIn state and the navigators start as The startnav gets called in app.js passing loggedIn state:

```
    class StartupNav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props.loggedIn);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          {this.props.loggedIn ? (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen name="MainContainer" component={MainContainer} />
            </>
          ) : (
            <Stack.Screen
              name="AuthStack"
              component={AuthStack}
              params="that" //props pass attempt which isnt successful
            />
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default StartupNav;
```

The authStack holds the login part as :

```
   class AuthStack extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('props from authstack', props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Then theres the login screen where I do the login logic and make an attempt to set the state in app.js loggedIn=true. After login is Successful I need to open the MainContainer which contains the loggedin app screens.

I am unable to pass props from the upper level navScreen to the lowers so that I could call prop function when login is successful. I tried as commented in the code like we normally do but this wasnt even valid.
Can anybody shed a light on this, or point me to the right direction.

I'm using react navigation 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do that using context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

I created an example snack here https://snack.expo.io/wzqRLEbi4

```js
const LoginContext = React.createContext({
  loggedIn: false,
  setLogin: () => {},
  setLogout: () => {}
});

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setLogin = () => {
      this.setState({
        loggedIn: true
      })
    };

    this.setLogout = () => {
      this.setState({
        loggedIn: false
      })
    };

    // State also contains the updater function so it will
    // be passed down into the context provider
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: false,
      setLogin: this.setLogin,
      setLogout: this.setLogout
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <LoginContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              {this.state.loggedIn ? (
                <>
                  <Stack.Screen name="MainContainer" component={MainContainer} />
                </>
              ) : (
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="AuthStack"
                  component={AuthStack}
                  params="that" //props pass attempt which isnt successful
                />
              )}
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </LoginContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

class Login extends Component {
  tryLogin = (setLogin) => {
    // your login logic 
    let isLoginSuccess = true;

    // if success
    setLogin();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <LoginContext.Consumer>
      {({setLogin}) => (
        <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.tryLogin(setLogin)}><Text>Login</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      )}
      </LoginContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, being a newbie in react, I think I hadn't come across the concept of contexts :)