# How to navigate between different stacks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

In my `App.tsx` file I have 3 stacks as follows:

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator()
const AuthStackScreen = () => (
  <AuthStack.Navigator>
    <AuthStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
  </AuthStack.Navigator>
)

export const HomeStack = createStackNavigator()
export const HomeStackScreen = () => (
  <HomeStack.Navigator>
    <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
    <HomeStack.Screen name="TestScreen" component={TestScreen} />
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
)

const RootStack = createStackNavigator()
const RootStackScreen = ({ isTokenValid }) => (
  <RootStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
    { isTokenValid 
    ? ( <RootStack.Screen name="App" component={HomeStackScreen} options={{headerShown:false}}/> ) 
    : ( <RootStack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthStackScreen} options={{headerShown:false}}/> ) 
    }
  </RootStack.Navigator>
)
```

Then I return the following:

```
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStackScreen isTokenValid={props.isTokenValid}/>
  </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

In my `Login.tsx` after successful login I want to navigate to HomeScreen that's under `HomeStackScreen` so I call for `navigation.navigate` as such:

```
const doLogin = ()=>{
    issueToken(phoneNumber,otp).then(res => { 
        navigation.navigate('HomeStackScreen', { screen: 'Root' });
    }).catch(err => alert(err));
}
```

However the navigation fails with this message:

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"HomeStackScreen","params":{"screen":"Root"}} was not handled by any navigator.
```

How can I navigate correctly between the two stacks?

Answer (score 2):

Your `RootStack` returns only a single stack, `HomeStackScreen` or `AuthStackScreen`, just one of them at a time. In your case, you are on `AuthStackScreen`, which means `HomeStackScreen` doesn't render. That's why you cannot navigate to `HomeStackScreen`.

In order to switch to HomeStackScreen, I think you need to update `isTokenValid` which I don't know how do you config it but you can use either redux or context.

This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61861273/1451753

Comment: Can't I just navigate between two nested stacks?

Comment: It's possible if your route stack includes both HomeStack and AuthStack, in that case you can navigate between screens in AuthStack to screens in HomeStack (which I don't think it's good for Auth flow). Your route stack choose one of them to render (controlled by isTokenValid props) and it's normal implementation for auth flow and it's also recommended in react-navigation website https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow